# Apple-Mach-O Linker Error UIKit iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a little lost as to why I am getting this error. Pretty much, I am abstracting some code to make a helper class that lets me reuse colors I use through out my app. The reason I don't understand why I am getting this error is because when I import my class to my NC Widget, no complaints. However, when I import my class to my TableViewController that is the base for my tableviews in my app, I get this error. UIKit is added to my frameworks, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ColorPalette : UIColor

+(UIColor *)setColorRed;
+(UIColor *)setColorBlue;
+(UIColor *)setColorGreen;
+(UIColor *)setColorOrange;


@end
```

And

```
#import "ColorPalette.h"

@implementation ColorPalette

+(UIColor *)setColorRed{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0f green:25/255.0f blue:36/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}

+(UIColor *)setColorGreen{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:29/255.0f green:156/255.0f blue:48/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}

+(UIColor *)setColorBlue{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0f green:174/255.0f blue:249/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}

+(UIColor *)setColorOrange{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:237/255.0f green:145/255.0f blue:50/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}


@end
```

So when I import it to my table view:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ColorPalette", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TableView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Top of .m TableView File

```
#import "TableView.h"
#import "ColorPalette.h"
```

Top of .h TableViewFile

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Show the top of your TableView.m and .h files - where are you importing the class?

Comment: Are you importing a `.m` file instead of a `.h` file?  Do you have two `.h` files importing each other causing a circular import?  Is your `Tableview.m` file listed under Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources?

Comment: @JAL I have added the top of the files. Thanks for the target-->Build Phases tip! That seemed to be it. I wonder why it wasn't added right away when I created the file.

Comment: @David no problem!  I have added that as an answer to this question.  Please mark it as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `Tableview.m` file listed under Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.